# using columns as lower and upper bound in RANDOM function in Teradata

Tags: teradata

This is Teradata specific question. In RANDOM function, I want the lower bound to be taken directly from one of the columns. e.g. I want a random value between age of the subscriber and till date. SO I want to put RANDOM(int_tenure, 0). I am receiving below error:

"Syntax error, expected something like an integer or a decimal number or a floating point number or '+' or '-' between '(' and the word 'int_tenure'"

Comment: Play around with modulo: `Random(0, 2147483647) MOD int_tenure)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the RANDOM only can take literals (no field/column names) and first parameter and to be lower/equal than second one. So in first step it's not possible. But you can work around: Generate a random factor [0;1] and apply this factor to the interval.

```
select 10 as lower_bound
      ,20 as upper_bound
--      ,random(lower_bound, upper_bound) -- will not work
      ,random(0, 1000)/1000.0000 as RND_Factor -- a random factor between 0 and 1
      ,(upper_bound-lower_bound)*RND_Factor+lower_bound;
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a good work around. I will try to frame my solution around it.